# Why 32bit CentOS 6 can run 64bit software?

Tags: centos, 64-bit, 32-bit

Screenshot of "uname -a", "/etc/redhat-release" and "file": 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R03G5.png)

It show that the "brook" executable is 64-bit and my CentOS 6 is 32-bit,  But the executable work correctly!

Here is the software download link: https://github.com/txthinking/brook/releases/download/v20181212/brook

Note that this machine is a VPS(Virtual Private Server) using OpenVZ tech.

Answer (score 2):

**CentOS 6**, even though it's a 32-bit operating system, can indeed run 64-bit software. Let me explain why:

1. **Kernel Compatibility**: The **kernel** is the core component of the operating system. CentOS 6 uses a **64-bit kernel**, which is compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit user space applications. This means that even though the OS itself is 32-bit, it can execute 64-bit programs.
2. **Multilib Support**: CentOS 6 includes **multilib support**. This allows it to fetch and install packages of different architectures (both 32-bit and 64-bit) from repositories. So, when you run a 64-bit program, the system handles it seamlessly.
3. **Fetching 64-bit Packages**: If you're curious about how this works, you can even convert a 32-bit CentOS installation to 64-bit by fetching the 64-bit kernel and rebooting. The system will then run the 64-bit kernel while still supporting 32-bit user space applications².

In summary, CentOS 6's clever combination of kernel compatibility and multilib support enables it to handle 64-bit software on a 32-bit base.

Source: Conversations with Bing， 2023/12/26

- (1) Convert 32-bit CentOS to 64-bit? - CentOS. https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=648.
- (2) Why 32bit CentOS 6 can run 64bit software? - Super User. [Why 32bit CentOS 6 can run 64bit software?](https://superuser.com/questions/1390475/why-32bit-centos-6-can-run-64bit-software).
- (3) redhat - RHEL 6 x64: running 32 bit applications - Server Fault. https://serverfault.com/questions/289400/rhel-6-x64-running-32-bit-applications.
- (4) 32bit 64bit - How to install 32-bit packages on a 64-bit CentOS .... https://serverfault.com/questions/512788/how-to-install-32-bit-packages-on-a-64-bit-centos.
- (5) undefined. https://github.com/txthinking/brook/releases/download/v20181212/brook.
- (6) undefined. http://centos.some-mirror.org/.../kernel-2.6.32-.